# Error al crear nuevo proyecto en XCode 7

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Tengo el siguiente error usando xcode, los textos se sobreponen unos sobre otros, esto ha ocurrido desde que instalé xcode, lamentablemente no tengo mucha experiencia en Mac por tanto les ruego ser lo más claros posibles a la hora de indicarme como resolver este problema. Estoy usando XCode 7. Gracias anticipadas!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A éstas personas les pasa lo mismo y no consiguieron arreglarlo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712664/xcode-7-3-1-new-project-templates-screens-text-is-overlapped & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800628/xcode-7-3-1-new-project-screen-fields. Dicen que es un bug del xCode. Intenta reinstalar..

Comment: Ya veo... voy a tener que reinstalar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Ricky Ten cuidado al actualizar a Xcode8. Al cambiar de lenguaje (Swift3), a mí los proyectos enteros se me desconfiguraron y los tuve que realizar de nuevo. Te sugiero hacerte una copia al menos antes de actualizar de tus proyectos con Swift2.2

Comment: Estaba pensando en que podría ocurrir ese problema man... gracias por tu comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Es un bug en el `Xcode`, simplemente **actualiza** al nuevo [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/).  A mi me ocurrió teniendo 7.3 usando `Yosemite`, no creo que tenga que ver con el OS pero si con el Xcode.

Comment: Es posible usar Swift 2 usando el nuevo Xcode?

Comment: Si usas el Xcode 8 me parece que la minima versión sería 2.3!, porque no cambias a Swift 3? o tienes algún proyecto con 2 ?

Comment: http://ashishkakkad.com/2016/09/steps-to-use-legacy-swift-in-xcode-8/

Comment: Estoy estudiando un curso con Swift 2, por ese motivo solamente... luego si me gustaría actualizar.